# How to understand the "Limits Step Size" and "Dominates Error" in Dymola

Tags: modelica, dymola

Dymola provides a function to analyze the numeric integration process, the main two results are "Limits Step Size" and "Dominates Error", I did some tests in my model, as showed in the following screenshot.

But I got a few questions when trying to analyze these data:

1. How does the integrator choose the integral step size in Dymola?
2. With "Limits Step Size", does this mean that the integrator has to use smaller step size so that integration of the corresponding variable could converge?
3. With "Dominate Error", does this mean that the corresponding variable causes a critical error during the iteration?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think "critical error" is not quite right. Dominates error means the variable has a greater estimated numerical error than the other variables, but that is then managed by the numerical solver.

Answer (score 3):

1. There are several different integrators in Dymola. Which step controller is used depends on what is most suitable for the chosen integrator. As has been previously noted the default integrator is Dassl which implements a BDF method. The logic for choosing step size is rather complex and it is intertwined with the integration order selection. In a nutshell, Dassl makes an estimate of the local error and then chooses step size and order to match the estimate with the user-provided tolerance. For details please refer to [Numerical Solution of Initial-Value Problems in Differential-Algebraic Equations](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9781611971224?mobileUi=0&), although there may be adaptions made to the solver used in Dymola.
2. "Limits step size" means that the error of this variable (and possibly also errors of other variables) was so large that the integrator had to discard the step and redo the step with a smaller step size.
3. From the Dymola manual:

   > The number of times the variable dominates the error, i.e. has an
   >   integration error larger than any other state variable.

   So, to answer your question: This does not mean a critical error (instead see "Limits step size" above). Rather, this just means that in this particular step the error of this state was the largest comparing over all states. The step may have been successful.

Answer (score 2):

I know more about OpenModelica than Dymola, but i guess the following is generally true:

1. The Dassl-Integrator (which is standard) uses the BDF-Method
   (backwards differentiation formulae) and solves a nonlinear system
   with newton to compute the state derivatives. Somewhere you can
   provide a integrator tolerance (i guess default would be 10^-6). The
   solver chooses the stepsize for newton such that it can respect that
   error tolerance. I think this is approximated by looking at the
   *regularity* of the jacobian. How close it is to singularity. Something something eigenvalues.
2. Limits step size: The variable was the most constraining one. Not for convergence but for error tolerance. Plus the step size had to actually be lowered, i think otherwise it is not tracked here.
3. Dominates error: This one is for convergence failures caused by this variable i think. It was furthest from the value where it should be. Usually something like full pivoting and small fiddling with values (in addition to lowering the step size) will be done here. About this last one i am not 100% sure though.